# Show error message in UI if response from API fails

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I build a pagination component based on the no of records received from the API its working fine if API fails or does not give any response the page crashes

I am expecting when there is no response from the API then it should display error message in the UI as "No Records Available",If the API fails then totalPageCount defined inside function paginationRange and lastPage is becoming undefined and the page is crashing

```
const DepositRates = () => {
    const [nriRates, setNriRates] = useState([]);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const getNriRates = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`API_URL`, {

            })
            setNriRates(res?.data?.data);
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log("nri rates ", err);
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getNriRates();
    }, []);
    const range = (start, end) => {
        let length = end - start + 1;
        return Array.from({ length }, (_, idx) => idx + start);
    };
    const paginationRange = () => {
        const totalPageCount = Math.ceil(nriRates.length / 10);
        return range(1, totalPageCount);
    }
    let lastPage = paginationRange()[paginationRange().length - 1]
    return (
        <>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Bank Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {nriRates.slice((currentPage - 1) * 10, currentPage * 10)?.map(item =>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{item.BankName}</td>
                        </tr>)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div className="pagination">
                {currentPage !== 1 &&
                    <a
                        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                        onClick={() => setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)}>
                        <i className="previous"></i>
                    </a>
                }
                {paginationRange().map((page) => {
                    return (
                        <a
                            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                            onClick={() => setCurrentPage(page)}
                            className={currentPage === page ? "active" : ""} >
                            {page}
                        </a>
                    )
                })}
                {currentPage !== lastPage &&
                    <a
                        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                        onClick={() => setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)}>
                        <i className="next"></i>
                    </a>
                }
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```